# Intel X86 emulator accelerator (HAXM installer) VT/NX not enabled

Tags: android, emulation, osx-yosemite, haxm

I`m asking how to enable my VT/NX for my MacBook, when I try to use X86 emulator, it appears to me that VT/NX NOT ENABLED, it had never seem this when I used 10.9 system, after I update my MacBook to Yosemite, it appears to me.

When I try to start my x86 emulator, it tells me:

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'X86'
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX is not installed on this machine (/dev/HAX is missing).
```

But the AVD shows me that I had installed HAXM.

When I try to install by myself again, installer prints `VT/NX NOT ENABLED`.

I can not post any images…

**to mindex's answer:**

I tried running all versions of Intel HAXM I could get:

```
IntelHAXM_1.0.8.dmg     
IntelHAXM_1.1.0_for_10.10.dmg     
IntelHAXM_1.1.0_below_10.10.dmg
```

But it did not work.

Comment: user3847306's answer is the way to go.

Comment: Why can't you accept the answer ? :(

Comment: Run ./sdk/extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager/HAXM\ installation  and enter password admin result: Silent installation Pass!, works for me.

Answer (score 135):

From the [Intel Instructions](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-mac-os-x)

"The SDK Manager will download the installer to the "extras" directory, under the main SDK directory. Even though the SDK manager says "Installed" it actually means that the Intel HAXM executable was downloaded. You will still need to run the installer from the "extras" directory to finish installation.

Extract the installer inside the "extras" directory and follow the installation instructions for your platform."

Comment: The problem persists even after executing HAXM installer. All this happened after upgrading to Yosemite.

Comment: This answer should appear on the top

Comment: For the lazy (android-sdk installed with homebrew): `cd /usr/local/Cellar/24.4.1/extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager && open IntelHAXM_6.0.1.dmg`. You may have to update your commands based on your install method and software versions.

Comment: After download your need to run :
`sudo /usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4.1/extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager/silent_install.sh`

Comment: If you want to run the .dmg through finder, you can unhide the Library folder from your user directory with this command:
`chflags nohidden ~/Library`

Comment: Paul Rad's comment worked a treat for me on OSX 10.11.4 with android-sdk/24.4.1_1/...

Comment: True! Android SDK manager was deceiving in this case. I had to rerun the installer `intelhaxm-android.exe` present at location `C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager` to get past the issue.

Answer (score 26):

Go to the **SDK manager** in your IDE and install the latest "**Intel HAXM**" and **start the emulator**.

If it is throwing the error as:

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'X86'
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX is not installed on this machine (/dev/HAX is missing).
```

It means that some hardware graphical features are to be assigned.So to overcome this problem just go to the path where you have your Android SDK installed.

### Windows

> C:\Android\SDK\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager

There you can find the file `intelhaxm-android.exe`.

### Mac OS X

On macOS there is a `IntelHAXM_X.X.X.dmg` file, mount it and you'll find an mpkg-file.

Install the file and restart all the applications using android emulator such as android studio, cmd, etc.

**Now try to open the emulator it will work fine**

Comment: You @user4683987 are the man (or woman)! works great. thanks!

Comment: I had to use the dmg, the sh files didn't work for me.

Comment: Path will be C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras

Answer (score 17):

You might be running an older version of Intel HAXM (or haven't installed it at all). Go to https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager and download/install the latest Intel HAXM package for MAC OS X.

EDIT: according to https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/506790 you should also make sure that Virtual PC/Parallel/VMWare is not running.

Answer (score 15):

Version 1.1.1 is the correct version for Yosemite. You need to download this directly from intel's site: https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager.

The one downloaded by SDK Manager is the older version (1.1.0). If you still want to run with version 1.1.0 - refer to the solution here - http://www.csell.net/2014/09/03/VTNX_Not_Enabled/

Comment: If you had HAX before yosemite and you upgraded, you will need to install it again (both the SDK and the Intel DMG, what will tell you that you already have it and it will be re-installed). That made it work for me.

Comment: 1.1.1 is now available in the Android SDK.

Answer (score 3):

In my case running Yosemite in VMWare Workstation 10.0.5 I had to:

1) Set kext to dev mode  (might not be needed anymore .... try first without it)

```
sudo nvram boot-args="kext-dev-mode=1"
```

Then reboot (power down VM) for step 2) below.

Details here: http://www.csell.net/2014/09/03/VTNX_Not_Enabled/

2) Add vhv.enable = "TRUE" to my VMX file and restart the VM

Details discussed here: https://communities.vmware.com/thread/416997?start=15&tstart=0

3) Install HAXM 1.1.1 as discussed above from the Intel 's site

(would love to post more links -> but have limit for 2 -> so vote for me so next time you will gert more .. :-))

Answer (score 3):

1.To install the virtualization driver:

Start the Android SDK Manager, select **Extras** and then select Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager.
After the download completes, execute **/extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager/IntelHAXM.exe.**
Follow the on-screen instructions to complete installation.

2.If it show any problem restart your computer and inter in BIOS an enable Virtualization Technology ...

3.To see your possessor is capable to virtualization go to the bellow link
http://ark.intel.com/Products/VirtualizationTechnology

Answer (score 0):

In many cases some antivirus also start HyperV with window start and does not allow HAXM to install. I faced this issue because of AVAST antivirus. So I uninstalled AVAST, then HAXM installed properly after restart. Then I re-installed AVAST.

So its just a check while installing as now even with AVAST installed back, HAXM works properly with virtual box and android emulators.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install Integrated Native Developer Experience 
" Is a cross-architecture productivity suite that provides developers with tools, support, and IDE integration to create high-performance C++/Java* applications for Windows* on Intel® architecture, OS X on Intel® architecture and Android* on ARM* and Intel® architecture."

[Integrated Native Developer Experience](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-inde)

Answer (score 0):

For IntelHAXM to install you have to activate Intel Virtual Technology.

To activate it, you have to restart your PC and go to BIOS. There is an option called Intel Virtual Technology that you have to enable to activate it.

After enabling it, reinstall IntelHAXM. That should solve the problem.