# Cannot run emulator in android studio...Getting HAXM error

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I am trying to setup android studio in my computer and almost everything's done but the last one and that is setting up the emulator. When I try to start it by clicking on AVD Manager I get this error.

```
Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
Output:
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!
```

I have tried to solve this issue by doing the following:

1. Going into the directory ........`sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\` and then running the exe file `"intelhaxm-android.exe"` to install manually. However, it did not work as well and gave the error saying that `VT not supported`.

To solve that problem I checked that in BIOS and found out it was already enabled.

Then, I searched more about it and found out that the anti virus may be causing it. So, about that, firstly, I do not have any Anti-virus installed yet and secondly I also deactivated Windows Firewall but still getting the error.

And,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,this question is not a duplicate of this question

[Emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29136173/emulator-error-x86-emulation-currently-requires-hardware-acceleration)

or any other one on stackoverflow.

Comment: Are you on Windows and have you enabled Hyper-V or installed Windows Phone SDK? Hyper-V and HAXM don't like each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have an old computer? I use Andriod Studio but I had the same problem trying to enable HAXM on my PC in order to use the emulator. My PC is several years old and runs Windows7.

I tried an alternate method but it was so slow that I have decided I needed to replace my PC.

Comment: Well, I am late in accepting the answer but the issue was solved by trying it on a new Laptop.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use Genymotion instead of HAXM. It's faster and saves you a lot of time.

https://www.genymotion.com

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issues with HAXM, I just found a solution. In the BIOS, I had "VT -d" enabled, I juste disabled it and everything worked well.
Hoping I helped you.
(look like VT -d is disable-ing VTx).

But Genymotion is faster than Android Studio emulator by the way, and comes with more options.