# Unable to launch android emulator in Mac

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, android-emulator

I have been working on an android project, I am using android studio on my ***iMAC[Software OS X 10.9.5, Graphics Intel HD Graphics 5000 1024 MB, Processor 1.4 GHz Intel Core i5]***.

When i try to open my application on an android emulator it get this error-

```
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!
```

I can find so many similar issues with solution on Google & SO, but i am unable to use those solutions for MAC???

I followed all the steps given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29136173/emulator-error-x86-emulation-currently-requires-hardware-acceleration) but with no luck, still unable to launch emulator. I think there is something to do with mac os.

Can anyone tell me how to do this on MAC ??

Thanks

Comment: Hi farhan, i also encountered the same issue in past, give me some time to recall the solution, will do answer for you soon.

Comment: Your quick response will be highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 33):

First, make sure that the Intel HAXM is up to date. You update it by opening the SDK and selecting it in the list. (As of 2016-07-08, the latests HAXM version is 6.0.3).

Then, on Mac, the Android SDK gets installed at: `/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk/`, therefore, you will need to run the script as sudo, as follows:

`sudo sh ~/Library/Android/sdk/extras/intel/Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager/silent_install.sh`

If all goes well, the script prints the message: `"Silent installation Pass!"`

Then, restart Android Studio and run your app with the desired AVD.

Comment: I was struggling with this issue for a while. I'd upvote this more if I could!

Comment: I was having issues with my emulator suddenly not starting as well. This fixed it for me - thanks!

Comment: Still struggling after doing as mentioned above. HAXM version is 6.1.1

Comment: Did the trick!! Why cant Android studio just take care of that instead of developers executing some hidden shells..

Answer (score 7):

I know I'm late, but here it goes.

1. Delete all AVD's that you currently have.
2. Go to `Preferences` >> `Android SDK` >> `SDK Tools`
3. Uninstall `Android Emulator`
4. Restart Android Studio.
5. Re-install `Android Emulator` from the same place.
6. Create a new emulator. And Voila !

What i personally did, in the process of fixing this.

1. I actually re-installed entire android studio. Followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625622/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio)
2. Fixed my `$PATH` variables. Followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42659272/emulator-on-android-studio-doesnt-start-after-sdk-tools-update-to-25-3-1/42661310)
3. Then i tried re-installing `Android Emulator`, which worked for me.

Hope this Helps.

Answer (score 0):

Problem in my case turned out to my `.zshrc` where my `ANDROID_HOME` was exported to a wrong value. Take a look at your `.bashrc` or `.zshrc`