# Emulator on Android Studio doesn't start after SDK tools update to 25.3.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

After updating my Android SDK tools today to 25.3.1, the emulator won't run anymore.

I can open the AVD Manager. When I hit "Play" on one of the emulators on the list, I see the bar below on Android Studio

[image]

But then after the progress bar reaches the end, nothing happens.

I see in the [release notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/sdk-tools.html#notes) that the latest update brought changes to the emulator so I'm wondering if that's a bug or I'm missing something about that.

I'm using Android Studio 2.3.

Any ideas?

Comment: My solution was not to run Vagrant (Virtualbox) in parallel. Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16168799/3045181)

Comment: The Android Emulator moved out of the SDK Tools Package in 25.3.1, so the solutions below about specifically adding the Android Emulator package in the SDK Manager in Android Studio 2.3 and higher is the right solution. (https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/emulator.html )

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I ran into the same problem after upgrading. I can't figure out what's causing the configuration problem but I did figure out a workaround.

First, I tried to launch the emulator from the command line:

```
$ emulator @<name_avd_image>
emulator: ERROR: This AVD's configuration is missing a kernel file! Please ensure the file "kernel-ranchu" is in the same location as your system image.
emulator: ERROR: ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is defined (<android>/sdk) but cannot find kernel file in <android>/sdk/system-images/ sub directories
```

You can get more information if you run `emulator` with the `-verbose` flag. I tried re-installing the system image (e.g. Android API 25 x86 w/ Google APIs), Android Emulator 25.3.1, and re-creating the AVD but nothing worked.

Finally as a workaround, I just copied all of the system files from the SDK system images directory into the AVD directory:

Example: Pixel XL (Android API 25 x86 w/ Google APIs)
SOURCE: `<android>`/sdk/system-images/android-25/google_apis/x86/
DESTINATION: ~/.android/avd/Pixel_XL_API_25.avd/

After that the emulator started right up. It's not ideal, but this was blocking my development so I had to get the emulator up and running again. I hope someone else will be able to figure out what broke in the configuration.

---

UPDATE: Figured out the configuration problem!

I noticed I periodically was seeing the console error "Your emulator is out of date, please update by launching Android Studio:" so I decided to check:

```
$ which emulator
<$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT>/tools/emulator
```

With help from this [thread](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=235461):

> The problem is there are two emulators: one in
>   `$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools`, another one in
>   `$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulator`. The one in `$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools`
>   cannot start. Place `$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/emulator` before
>   `$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/tools` in your `$PATH` variable, it should fix the
>   problem.

NOTE: For most Mac users, you can edit your `~/.bash_profile` to change these settings and then run `$source ~/.bash_profile` to load the updates. In my particular case, I also had old values for $ANDROID_HOME that I had to clear out.

Comment: You helped me so much. Thanks! A fix: for more info, you add `-verbose` rather than `--verbose`

Comment: My emulator now open but stay on black "android" screen

Comment: Edit: I fix my problem fixing my path (variable) to "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk"

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 20):

The real problem, at least over Ubuntu 16.10 and 17.04 and Andoid Studio 2.4 Preview 7 (but could happen with any Debian derivative and previous versions of Android Studio), is that Google is distributing a non working **libstdc++** library with the emulator tools. They're distributing 6.0.18 version, but i found that the working one is 6.0.22.

**EDIT: There are reports that 6.0.21 version of libstdc++ works as well as 6.0.22.**

So, you have 2 options:

**Option 1**

`rm` the previous non working Google's libs in /yoursdkpàth/emulator/lib64/libstdc++

Download and extract libs from [libstdc++ official package](https://packages.debian.org/es/sid/amd64/libstdc++6/download) in /yoursdkpàth/emulator/lib64/libstdc++

Don't try to install the .deb, extract the files/binaries from inside it (the 2 binaries are in a folder named "lib") and manuallly copy them on the recommended path.

**Option 2**

Create a simlink to the lib distributed with Ubuntu, which already is 6.0.22 version

```
cd ~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++/

mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.bak

mv libstdc++.so.6.0.18 libstdc++.so.6.0.18.bak

ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 ~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++/libstdc++.so.6

ln -sf /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.22 ~/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++/libstdc++.so.6.0.22
```

**IMPORTANT 1: As Google seems to be not aware of the problem, on every update they make to the Android Emulator package in Android Studio, they break the funcionality replacing your working SDK C++ libs with the broken/older ones. The solution is to repeat any of the above procedures.**

**IMPORTANT 2: This is only valid if your AVDs are configured for use your PC GPU as host for video accelaration (Hardware GLES 2.0). Selecting Sofware GLES 2.0 on your AVD will work without any of the suggested changes, but your emulator will turn painfully slow.**

Comment: I applied *Option 2*. After that, emulator just open for 1 second and then automatically closed!

Comment: @HasanAbdullah Check your Android Studio logs. That seems to be another kind of problem not related to the hardware acceleration. By the way, since 26.x.x emulator the problem of this post is solved, in case you want to try Android Studio 3 preview versions.

Comment: This worked for me on BBQLinux, which is an arch distro. The only difference was the location of the libraries which were in `/usr/lib` directly instead of `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`

Answer (score 13):

**Have you check the Android emulator installed in the **SDK Tools**?

Go to **Setting-> sdk-tools**.

See whether Android is installed or not.

I have face same problem. when I checked the SDK Tools, I found that the Android emulator was not installed.

[image]

Comment: This helped me to solve the issue after searching for hours a solution. Thank you for sharing this small detail.

Answer (score 6):

The `libstdc++.so.6` is the cause (as pointed out by @doruMarinau); Android Studio 2.3 moved the file to a new folder `your_sdk/emulator/lib64`.

If using Linux, create a symlink for it:

```
$ ln -sf /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6  /your_sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++/libstdc++.so.6
```

Comment: Thank you! For the record, this fixes it if there are libGL errors when trying to run the emulator from command line, like libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so

Answer (score 3):

The solution is:
Tools - Android - Sdk manager
tab Sdk tools
install emulator 25.3.1

Comment: I see there 26.0.0, how can I go back?

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

Go to AVD Manager, then, in the Actions column, click on the arrow that points dawn and select "Wipe Data".
After this, try to run the emulator.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++` move `libstdc++.so.6` and `libstdc++.so.6.0.18` to myfolder (I created this) (or any other location) as backup and copy `libstdc++.so.6`, `libstdc++.so.6.0.21` from `usr/lib64`; try again to launch your virtual device.

Comment: I don't have `libstdc++` in lib64 folder.

Answer (score 1):

It’s a libGL error and libstdc++ issue. Cannot launch AVD in emulator.
It’s a know bug and you can easily beat it with some simple steps.

I have tested this solution on a Ubuntu 16.10 64bit

**Solution:**

```
$adb kill-server
$adb start-server
```

After this start your emulator from the Android studio. If this doesn't work then go ahead for the next solution.

**Alternative solution:**

First, install some packages and libs:

```
$sudo apt-get install lib64stdc++6:i386
$sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

Second, tweak some links:

```
$ cd YOURPATH/Android/Sdk/tools/lib64
$ mv libstdc++/ libstdc++.bak
$ ln -s /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6  libstdc++
```

Third, relaunch your AVD device and test it.

Answer (score 0):

It's been driving me nuts for the last few days. Here's what worked for me:

`ANDROID_HOME, ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` variables in "System Environment Variables" were different from `Android Studio -> Settings -> Android SDK Location`. So when I changed the environment variables, AVD started!

(After changed the environment variable, you should restart the Android Studio)

Answer (score 0):

The only solution which worked for me, was to install following missing libraries:

```
$sudo apt-get install lib64stdc++6:i386
$sudo apt-get install mesa-utils
```

Once you have them, update the one there in sdk's emulator with these as following:

```
$ ln -sf /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6  /home/[YOUR_SYSTEM_USERNAME]/emulator/lib64/libstdc++/libstdc++.so.6
```

Launch your emulator again and it will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

As of this release, the Android Emulator will be released separately from the SDK Tools.
so just install android Emulator using sdk tools in your android studio

Answer (score 0):

My problem was `ANDROID_SDK_HOME` pointing to `d:\.android` instead of `d:\`. Could not find the images anymore.