# Click Run in eclipse and nothing happens

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have situation in eclipse, before i work in eclipse app was running fine, but today, not working. I click on progect->run as->android application. And nothing happens, no error, no popup window, also nothing in console:

```
2015-10-15 11:01:03 - test] Android Launch!
[2015-10-15 11:01:03 - test] adb is running normally.
[2015-10-15 11:01:03 - test] Performing com.example.test.MainActivity activity launch
[2015-10-15 11:01:03 - test] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'Nexus_5_API_22_x86'
[2015-10-15 11:01:03 - test] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Nexus_5_API_22_x86'
[2015-10-15 11:01:04 - Emulator] emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
[2015-10-15 11:01:04 - Emulator] Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
[2015-10-15 11:01:04 - Emulator] CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!
```

Please tell me, how can i run my app in eclipse to android phone?

Comment: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29136173/emulator-error-x86-emulation-currently-requires-hardware-acceleration

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd

Answer (score 1):

If you set GPU emulation to Yes for your AVD, then graphics acceleration is automatically enabled when you run it. If you did not enable GPU emulation when you created the AVD, you can still enable it at runtime.

To enable graphics acceleration at runtime for an AVD:

If you are running the emulator from the command line, just include the -gpu on option:

emulator -avd  -gpu on

Note: You must specify an AVD configuration that uses Android 4.0.3 (API Level 15, revision 3) or higher system image target. Graphics acceleration is not available for earlier system images.

If you are running the emulator from Android Studio, run your Android application using an AVD with the -gpu on option enabled:

In Android Studio, click your Android application module folder and then select Run > Edit Configurations...

In the left panel of the Run/Debug Configurations dialog, select your Android run configuration or create a new configuration.

Under the Target Device options, select the AVD you created in the previous procedure.

In the Emulator tab, in the Additional command line options field, enter:
-gpu on
Run your Android project using this run configuration.