# how to fix emulator error : x86 emulation?

Tags: android

how can i fix this error"emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!
" if my processor is AMD E1,

Comment: Before you post any question do check if its already posted or not. Check it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29136173/emulator-error-x86-emulation-currently-requires-hardware-acceleration).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error in launching AVD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd)

Answer (score 0):

Intel HAXM does not work with AMD processors. Try some other software based emulator like genymotion