# Error while starting emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, haxm

I am running an android application on emulator. It was working fine till yesterday and today I updated android studio. I am getting following error.
How to resolve this?

> emulator: WARNING: Increasing RAM size to 1GB emulator:
>    ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration! Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable. 
>   CPU acceleration status: HAXM must be updated (version 1.1.1 < 6.0.1).

Comment: Hello,I suggest you to update your android sdk ,and update required hardware accelaration.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26355645/error-in-launching-avd

Comment: my suggestion is use genymotion    [this](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download)

Comment: Also see [Emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29136173/608639), [Error in launching AVD with AMD processor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26355645/608639), [Error while starting emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34282243/608639), etc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Go To Your **Android SDK ----> Run SDK Manager as Admin.**

GO down and **check Extras---> Update Intel Emulator Accelator (HAXM installer).**

Then Restart Android Studio and Run Your AVD.

Comment: It was not getting updated in SDK Manager. I downloaded it from Intel website and updated manually.

Comment: If you have downloaded HAXM 6.0.x and it says you still have HAXM 1.1.1, see the next answer. Note that it's now called intelhaxm-android, not intelhaxm.

Answer (score 18):

I had to uninstall version 1.1.1 by going to:

```
C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager>
```

then type in `silent_install.bat -v` to verify the current version.
then `silent_install.bat -u` to uninstall
then `silent_install.bat`  to install version 6.0.1 in my case.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue, apparently, i had installed **HAXM** manually directly from Intel. And I guess it's conflicting with that of the Android SDK.

So I downloaded and installed the updated version from Intel at [HAXM download page](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager/). This solved my HAXM [conflict] problem

Answer (score 4):

At first you have to uninstall HAXM from:

> Control panel > Add/remove program

After that go to [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager) and download HAXM and install it manually.

This worked for me .

Answer (score 3):

If the SDK manager thinks you have the latest version, simply go to the **SDK folder** and run the `silent_install.bat` file.

Mine was here:

`C:\Users\userid\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\silent_install.bat`

It will start working immediately, no need to restart Android Studio. It's probably because the SDK manager had insufficient permissions.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to install version 6.0.3 after I downloaded the update, **intelhaxm-android.exe** showed a windowed message for 1/10sec (i.e. I could not read it, since I don't know how to stop time) and did nothing after that. I had to locate and run **'setup.exe'** among the files extracted by intelhaxm-android.exe. This time there was a prompt saying *"Intel Hardware Accelarated Manager version 1.1.1 is already installed. Do you want to install version 6.0.3?"* I replied 'Yes', an installation Wizard was opened and that was it. HAXM 6.0.3 was finally installed and the emulator run again.
(Note: You might have to locate the exact 'setup.exe' file (there are four od them) that was run in the installation. You can locate it towards the end of the log file created by intelhaxm-android.exe. The message is something like that: *"{temp folder}\Intel\HAXM\6.0.3\2016-09-13_14-35-22\setup.exe was launched".*)