# error coming in android studio while running the app

Tags: android

emulator: WARNING: Crash service did not start
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAXM must be updated (version 1.1.1 < 6.0.1).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error while starting emulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34282243/error-while-starting-emulator)