# Android emulator on Hyper V – how to get hardware acceleration

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, windows-10, hyper-v

Microsoft recently announced support for running android emulator on hyper V.(https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2018/05/08/hyper-v-android-emulator-support/)

I am trying to start the Android emulator 27.2.9.0 on my Windows 10 (April 2018 Update) Hyper V enabled machine with the following command :

```
> cd C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\emulator
> emulator -avd <avd name> -feature WindowsHypervisorPlatform
```

And I am getting the following error message:

```
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please ensure Windows Hypervisor Platform (WHPX) is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: Please disable Hyper-V before using the Android Emulator.
 Start a command prompt as Administrator,
 run 'bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off', reboot.
```

I have added the "WindowsHypervisorPlatform = on" line to C:\Users<your-username>.android\advancedFeatures.ini, but that didn't help.

What am I missing?

Comment: After trying all the mentioned answers, and if none of them worked for window 10 revision 1709 and above, refer the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63087853/3049065) which can solve this issue.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Well, it turned out that I had "Hyper-V" enabled, but **"Windows Hypervisor Platform**" was not enabled. (Who knew these are two different things!). Once it was enabled the emulator started to work.

[image]

Comment: I don´t have this Windows Hypervisor Platform, even if my windows is updated. What´s wrong?

Comment: Thanks!  I've been chasing a bunch of red herrings with avdmanager, sdkmanager and tns.  This was the ticket.

Comment: Even though I followed the MS article I totally missed the second Hyper V section to turn on. Thank you. I am referring to this MS article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?tabs=vswin&pivots=windows

Comment: Be aware, my computer blue screened attempting to enable this the first time.  After it rebooted, I tried again and it worked.  Just letting you know in case you have anything open that should be saved/closed beforehand.

Comment: @LittleMonkey, are you using Windows Home edition? Hyper-V is available on 64-bit versions of Windows 10 Pro, Enterprise, and Education. It is not available on the Home edition.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/about/

Comment: Wow.  They need to add this to the docs.

Answer (score 11):

I just had to uninstall the "Hyper-V Hypervisor" and the emulator started working. I'm using Windows 10 (1803). The emulators stop working if I install "Hyper-V Hypervisor".

[image]

Comment: Cheers! That was my issue as well.

Comment: It helped me too :) (Visual Studio 2019 + Windows 10)

Answer (score 9):

With latest Android Studio, you do not need Hyper-V on AMD.

Just enable "Windows Hypervisor Platform" (turn windows features on and off screen) and x86 images should automatically become usable

[image]

Comment: This did the tric for me on a Ryzen CPU, I wish it was obvious in the official docs, but AMD's not even mentioned (only Intel and HAXM).

Comment: I was missing the Hypervisor Driver for AMD processors. 
To install it go to (in VS) "Extras > Android > SDK Manager". Then in the SDK Manager go to "Tools > Extras > Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD processors"

Answer (score 6):

There are a few things I did to get this working on my pc.

- Install Visual Studio 15.8 Preview 1 or later
- Remove and Reinstall the emulator within the Visual Studio Preview
- I removed HAXM from the "Extras" within the android sdk manager (from
  the visual studio menu).
- The path for the advancedFeatures.ini is C:\Users\Your Username\advancedFeatures.ini to set WindowsHypervisorPlatform = on
- Open Turn Windows features on or off and select Hyper-V and the Windows Hypervisor Platform checkboxes. (Requires restart)

There is another guide from Microsoft here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?tabs=vswin

Comment: Thanks for the Microsoft link.  It made me realise that I didn't have the latest update (version 1803) after recently upgrading to Windows 10 Pro.

Comment: My 12 month old installation of Android SDK and emulator, as of today, is running on Hyper-V with_out_ requiring Visual Studio or Xamarin software.

Comment: I resolved the problem by removing HAXM from Android SDK :)

Answer (score -1):

Run the below command in `cmd` opened as Administrator to disable `hyper-v` and then reboot the machine:

`bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off`

This command works for me.

Comment: This will break many other things in the system.