# Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration! Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1

Tags: android

```
Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration! Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1
```

[image]

Comment: It lacks description, but it represents the error perfectly.

Answer (score 35):

I was having the exact same problem. This is how I fixed it (for Windows):

1. Go into Android Studio and open the SDK Manager (under the Tools menu)
2. Under SDK Platforms tab, UNCHECK any boxes that are selected. If there are any boxes checked, that means they are installed - but we want to uninstall them for now.
3. Go to the SDK Tools tab. Make sure that Android Emulator, Android SDK Platform-Tools, and Android SDK Tools are all checked.
4. In the same tab, make sure that the Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator is UNCHECKED. If it is checked, that means it is installed, but we want to uninstall it for now. (I also uninstalled Android SDK Build-Tools, but I'm not all sure if that step was necessary.)
5. Go to this link: https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases/download/v7.2.0/haxm-windows_v7_2_0.zip    This is where we re-install the Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator. Save it to your Downloads folder, and extract files. Do not launch any setup wizards yet!
6. Shut down your computer. As you start it up again, launch BIOS (For Windows 10, hold down F10 key). In BIOS, press the right arrow until you get to the third tab. Under there, go down to an option for Virtualization. If it is set as Disabled, use the Enter key to set it to Enabled. Press F10 to save and exit.
7. Go back into your Downloads folder, or wherever you saved the Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (aka haxm). Double click on the file intelhaxm-android. This will install haxm to your computer.
8. Go into Android Studio, and open up the SDK Manager again. In the SDK Platforms tab, re-check the boxes for the APIs that you want. This will re-install them, since earlier we uninstalled them. (I tried to install API 28, but afterwards it was labeled Partially Installed, so I went ahead and downloaded APIs 27 and 26.) Click Apply and allow it/them to install.
9. Go to the tab SDK Tools and re-check the boxes for Android SDK Build-Tools and Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator. Click Apply and allow them to install.
10. At this point, I had already set up a Virtual Device with API 26, and it successfully loaded. Make sure that if you are setting up a Virtual Device, that you set it for an API that you installed in Step 8.

That was my solution, I hope it works for you!

Comment: Thank you for this detailed step by step, finally solved my emulator issue!

Comment: I had this same problem, and it was sufficient to only uninstall and re-install the Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator **after** enabling Hardware Virtualization in the BIOS.

Comment: Though it refers to Xamarin development, I found [this page on how to install and verify HAXM helpful](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/android-emulator/hardware-acceleration?tabs=vswin#haxm) also (though it didn't solve my problem---reinstalling HAXM after enabling hardware virtualization in the BIOS did).

Comment: step 6 was enough for me, there was no need to reinstall anything

Comment: I did steps 1-4, then 8 and 9. Android Studio prompted me to enable virtualization (step 6). The haxm installation occurred automatically through Android Studio.

Answer (score 32):

An easier solution that worked for me (windows 10, Android Studio 3.1.4), just reinstall the HAXM installer:
1. Open SDK Manager > SDK Tools
2. Uncheck Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM Installer) -> Click Apply
3. Check Again
4. After the installation process, you should be able to launch the emulator.

Comment: For my Docker bro's out there, you'll likely have Hyper-V enabled so need to disable it and restart as a pre-requisite.

Answer (score 8):

For me, I didn't noticed that I had hyper-v enabled when I first installed Android Studio. When trying to reinstall the emulator I got an error message letting me know it needed to be disabled for HAXM to work. So, I first needed to disable hyper-v:

1. Press Windows Key Type "Turn windows features on or off"
2. Find and uncheck Hyper-V
3. Restart

Then you just need to re-install the emulator

1. Open Tools->SDK manager in Android Studio
2. Click the SDK tools tab
3. Uncheck the Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator box
4. Click Apply
5. Check the Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator box
6. Click Apply

The emulator should download and reinstall and should give you a success message. Now the emulator should start.

Comment: And don't forget to activate Virtualization in your System BIOS as well.