# I just got into React Native and was trying to create a virtual device on Android Studio but it keeps displaying the following error, any suggestions?

Tags: android, react-native, android-emulator

12:32 AM    Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!

12:32 AM    Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Have you installed Intel's HAXM?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration! Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51399634/emulator-emulator-error-x86-emulation-currently-requires-hardware-acceleratio)

Comment: Install HAXM from android studio and it works.