# cant windows hypervisor platform option in my windows 10 pro

Tags: powershell, android-studio, hypervisor

I enabled the `hyper-v` option in windows features ...made hyper-v services automatic from task manager, but Android Studio Canary is still showing

```
emulator x86:emulation needs hardware acceleration.
emulator ended with exit code 1
```

Please help my laptop is an amd ryzen 5 2500u ,8gb ram,1TB hdd

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51399634/emulator-emulator-error-x86-emulation-currently-requires-hardware-acceleratio

Comment: this solution is for intel processors not for amd processor

Comment: In the question you have mentioned that you have enabled but, in the answer you specified **windows hyper-visor platform is not available in windows features**. How is this possible?

Comment: That's the issue i got hyper-v option enabled and cant see any option named windows hypervisor platform...and i need that feature to be enabled for working of android studio emulator

Comment: I am using windows 10 pro

Comment: Did you enable Intel virtualization technology from Bios?

Comment: @karma4917, I have Hyper-V available but not Windows Hypervisor Platform, also. Hyper-V is used for Docker, so BIOS virtualization options are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

- Check your Windows 10 version: right click on start button, System. See version number in Windows specifications. Mine was **1709** while Windows Update was apparently "up to date".
- *Windows Hypervisor Platform* feature depends on Windows 10 version **1803** (aka "Redstone 4")

If like me, your Windows is not really up to date:

- In "Windows Update" / "Check for Updates", click on "Advanced options" to see if you are on the branch "Targeted". If not, you receive feature updates to Windows 10 very lately (adapted to big organizations). After the targeted channel branch selected, check for update. You should receive the new one(s).