# Android Studio 3.3.1 Emulator bug

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I'm a new Android Studio user, but I've already done something in the last few days.

I have only a problem with the emulator. I tried to run my code with a normal Virtual Device, but every time I always got the same error:

```
Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!

Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1
```

I tried to find a solution in the internet, and I found that the problem was my computer (it is an AMD) and I had to download the "armeabi" version when I created a new virtual device.

It worked (I have no more errors), but my emulator is always black and I cannot see anything. I was forced to use Debug USB on my personal phone, to plug in and use it (and it works) but I'd like to solve the problem with the Android Studio emulator. My Android Studio version is 3.3.1, the latest.

Obviously when I have a preview clicking on the file "activity_main.xml" I can see the right output.

Normally I use Nexus 5 and I've tried with Marshmallow and Nougat.

Comment: Ciao! It seems your emulator did not fully started. Have you wait for it properly? The process can last... Or: have you tried to build a less power demanding virtual device (i.e., lower Api, lower resolution, mem etc)? Maybe... very few chances but: maybe you screen resolution (i.e., the display of you pc, where android studio runs) is hidding emulator contents. Try with a smaller res.

Comment: have you tried this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51399634/emulator-emulator-error-x86-emulation-currently-requires-hardware-acceleratio

Comment: Ciao! I have tried both solutions but they didn't work. Or, I can see, trying to change VM Heap (as the solutions below) only "android". It tries to connect to the virtual device, but after 6 minutes it writes:Error while waiting for device: Timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online.

Answer (score 0):

Increase your VM Heap & try it again.

- Tools -> Android -> AVD Manager.
- Select a virtual device and click on its pencil icon (edit)
- Click on Show Advanced Settings.
- Under "Memory and Storage" change "VM Heap"

[image]
If above is not helpful, Please Check "Wipe user data" in the Launch Option

```
Go to Android Virtual Device Manager->Select your device->Start->Check "Wipe user data"->Launch
```

Comment: thank you for your help, unfortunately it did'n work but i can see now written "android", but, it tries to connect to the virtual device but after 6 minutes it writes: Error while waiting for device: Timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

make sure that Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator is active

Comment: Now go to your SDK directory C:\users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\ and run the file named intelhaxm-android.exe.

In case you get an error like "Intel virtualization technology (vt,vt-x) is not enabled". Go to your BIOS settings and enable Hardware Virtualization.

Comment: @AndreaStaccoli and then Restart Android Studio and then try to start the AVD again.

It might take a minute or 2 to show the emulator window.

Installation of Intel HAXM consists of two steps. First, you need to download it using SDK manager. Then you need to run intelhaxm-android.exe to install Intel HAXM. The reason I'm writing this comment is that I downloaded HAXM, and the error dialog continued showing up until I ran intelhaxm-android.exe –

Comment: Yeah i'd already seen this solution but the error that I get is not "it's not enabled" but "it's not supported"