# Android Studio Hardware acceleration issue after installing hxam enable virtualization nad disabling hyper-v

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-virtual-device, hardware-acceleration

I have setup Android studio , Hxam is install version 7.3 , virtualization is enable and hyder-v is disable , still I am having this error

"Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration! "

what to do all answers on internet not helpful

Answer (score 0):

Finally Some article help , here you can follow steps if you already install intel H-XAM , Virtualization On and hyper-v disable and still you are having above error

[Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration! Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51399634/emulator-emulator-error-x86-emulation-currently-requires-hardware-acceleratio)

I think this is becuase of intel HXAM version 7.3 is not stable.