# ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration! (Android Studio)

Tags: android, haxm

I'm currently have a problem with my Android Studio because I cannot run any application using an emulator.
The full error that comes up when trying to run an application is...

> Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware
>   acceleration!
>
> Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1

I have Intel Haxm fully installed (when running intelhaxm-android.exe it only gives me the option to remove) and have tried using both the API 27 and 28.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Have you tried x86_64 emulators?

Comment: @shizhen Yes just installed x86_64 and recieved the same error :(

Comment: @Taylor am facing exactly the same problem did you manage to solve it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29136173/emulator-error-x86-emulation-currently-requires-hardware-acceleration)

Answer (score 6):

I was having the same issue. 
Doing the following steps solved the issue.

1. Check if **Virtualization** is **enabled** under BIOS. If not, do so. It is usually under CPU settings.
2. In Android studio, check that under S**DK_Manager>Android_SDK>SDK Tools> Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer)** is **checked**. If not,check it and press OK. It will install HAXM.
3. If the problem still persists (Which is the usual case for latest Windows 10 updates), on windows control panel search for **Turn Windows features on or off**. Put **check** in **Window HyperVisor Platform** as below.

[image: Windows HyperVisor On]

Now, run AVD and it should work.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and found out that you need to enable hardware acceleration in the BIOS.

Comment: Same here, my hardware virtualization was disabled

Answer (score 1):

for anyone else having this exact issue i was able to solve this issue by

1. uninstalling intel Haxm
2. enable virtualization in BIOS
3. enable NX/ND bit or execute disable feature in BIOS
4. re-installing intel Haxm

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your **HAXM** from SDK manager, i attach my settings for **Android Studio 3.1.2** here: 
[image]

And, remember that you should have installed the correct Android Studio, i.e. 32-bit or 64-bit according to your computer.

**---- Edit ----**

If still got problems, try the steps here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31458503/8034839

Comment: Double checked the application and I do have the correct version installed - also reffering to your screenshot above I have the latest version currently installed so no updates needed

Comment: Helped me to fix: "I fixed it by uninstall and install HAXM again "