# Emulator ERROR for android studios but intel x86 is already installed

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, android-sdk-manager

When I run my android virtual device I get an error like this.

Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!

I check the Android SDK Manager system to then download. However, it's already installed.

[image]

I've searched for solutions but the solutions always solved it with installing intel x86.

As a summary, my virtual device won't run cause of an emulator error stated above. However intel x86 is already installed but it still won't work. Is there a way to fix this?

Edit:

Thank you to those who have answered, I'm pasting links down below if anyone else has this problem and need help.

[Emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29136173/emulator-error-x86-emulation-currently-requires-hardware-acceleration) answered by Daniil Shevelev.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7U-e3Ui-NhU to enable VT-x.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration! (Android Studio)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51489362/error-x86-emulation-currently-requires-hardware-acceleration-android-studio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hardware acceleration in present in BIOS. you have to enable it. If it does not present there, then possibly your system does not support it. You can use ARM system image.