# Trouble with intel HAXM on Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I was trying to create a AVD on android studio.But i could not I had already installed intel HAXM. 
I have tried

```
1. I have installed intel HAXM through android Studio.
2. I have tried installing intel HAXM through intel website. 
3. I executed silent_install in intel HAXM folder
4. I restarted my android studio after silent.install
```

The error i got

```
6:25 PM Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!

6:25 PM Emulator: CPU acceleration status: Unable to open HAXM device: ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

6:25 PM Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1
```

In my PC intel HAXM is installed at

```
C:\Users\Pie\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager
```

- I have gone through the solution provided in this post
  [Emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29136173/emulator-error-x86-emulation-currently-requires-hardware-acceleration)
- I have enabled intel virtualization in BIOS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29136173/emulator-error-x86-emulation-currently-requires-hardware-acceleration)

Comment: @SaikrishnaRajaraman i have already tried solution provided in this post. But it did not work!

Comment: Are you using version 7.2.0 ?

Comment: @JaswantSingh Yes, I am using 7.2.0 of intel x86 HAXM

Comment: Uninstall it and install version 7.1.0, it will work for sure. If you can’t find a download link, just let me know

Comment: https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases/download/v7.1.0/haxm-windows_v7_1_0.zip   Here’s the download link for the version 7.1.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using version HAXM version 7.2.0, uninstall it and install version 7.1.0. Doing this solved my problem

[Link for version 7.1.0 windows edition](https://github.com/intel/haxm/releases/download/v7.1.0/haxm-windows_v7_1_0.zip)

Comment: I do not understand what was wrong with 7.2.0 version of intel x86 HAXM.And why it did not worked?. And Thanks help @Jaswant Singh

Comment: Actually there’s some certificate related issue in version 7.2.0 which windows doesn’t let install completely, it will show you that it is installed but actually it isn’t. I’m glad that version 7.1.0 worked for you. Cheers!