# how to enable emulator in android studio?

Tags: android

I've been learning Android studio and android app development for a while now and I've been installing emulator .I recently installed the Nexus 5S API 24 but that showed some emulator errors
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjgiP.png)

And then I thought the problem is with the API and so downloaded an emulator with lower API i.e; NEXUS 4 API 18 and that is also not running showing the same error. I thought the problem is with android Studio and hence I uninstalled the whole Android 
Studio and then downloaded it again.But again the same errors show up.
I  tried connecting my phone as an emulator instead of downloading an emulator.
But then, something showed up like in the picture below
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTqlf.png)

Mine is a Gionee P7 phone .

Any help on this issue would be helpful .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29136173/emulator-error-x86-emulation-currently-requires-hardware-acceleration)

Comment: Please add the errors as text instead of pictures.

Comment: @HamzaAnis Sure, I will the next time. I'm new to Stack OVerflow so slowly learning the function of it . :)

Answer (score 0):

Open the SDK Tools (Tools> SDK Manager> SDK Tools) to check if you have installed the Intel X86 Accelerator, if not, check the box and apply, then restart your AS, it should work.

Still recommend you to use real device to run your application, since the emulator really cost a lot of memory resources.