# Hardware acceleration doesn't work in Android Studio despite intelhaxm being installed

Tags: android, android-studio

I have intelhaxm installed and use a quite new Lenovo Thinkpad. When I try to start an emulated device I get the error message:

```
Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration
```

What do I have to do to get start the emulator?

(I don't get the error message `HAX kernel module is not installed` that the linked question is about)

Comment: have u check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29136173/emulator-error-x86-emulation-currently-requires-hardware-acceleration

Comment: this might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29136173/emulator-error-x86-emulation-currently-requires-hardware-acceleration

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29136173/emulator-error-x86-emulation-currently-requires-hardware-acceleration)

Comment: This is the steps to perform: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31458503/8034839

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I had to deinstall and then reinstall HAXM. When I reinstalled it told me that there might be a conflict with Hyper-V visualisation and after I switched that off it finally worked.

Answer (score 0):

In android Studio Go to

**File->Settings-->Apperance&Behaviour-->System Settings-->Android SDK->** then tap on SDK Tools and update the Intel x86 emulator Accelator

Comment: `Intel x86 emulator Accelator` is already marked as being installed with version 7.3.0 at the setting.

Comment: What do you mean with invalidate catches?

Comment: In android studio go to file-->Invalidate catches and restart

Answer (score 0):

Download the HAXM manager and install it manually.

https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-intel-haxm