# Not able to run android studio

Tags: android-studio

I'm not able to run my "Hello World" application in android studio and shows the following error:

> 19:38  Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
>
> 19:38  Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1

I have checked in my Android SDK manager,intelX86 Emulator Accelerator(HAXM installer) was installed.

How can i clear this bug?

Comment: Please add you current code that you're having trouble with.

Comment: See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29136173/emulator-error-x86-emulation-currently-requires-hardware-acceleration)