# Android Studio cant get the emulator to run

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried Android Studio on 3 different devices and I keep getting the following errors when trying to run:

```
Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!

Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1
```

It has to be something I'm doing wrong but I have no idea whatsoever what I am doing. Its driving me mad! Can anyone offer any help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29136173/emulator-error-x86-emulation-currently-requires-hardware-acceleration)

Answer (score 1):

You are probably missing HAXM which is the hardware accelerator by Intel.
You should install it via the SDK manager.
Go to Tools->SDK Manager.
Then click on SDK Tools tab and see if the HAXM is checked.
[SDK Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvYLm.jpg)