# Testing Apps on virtual devices in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I need your help.

I have recently started developing my first Android App, using youtube tutorials, and I can across this Error messages when I tried to Run a simple "Hello, world" app on a virtual device:

> Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
>
> Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1

I do have the HAXM installed, so what sort of hardware acceleration is needed?

When I searched for an answer someone suggested changing the "Graphics" in the virtual device edit window. But the "Graphics" option is set to "Automatic" and I am unable to change it.  can anyone please help me?

Oh, and it also gave me this error message in the "Run" window:

> Error while waiting for device: The emulator process for AVD Nexus_5X_API_28 was killed.

Please help me!

Comment: use genymotion or nox

Comment: did you check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29136173/emulator-error-x86-emulation-currently-requires-hardware-acceleration

Comment: I did check that one out but I already have the HAXM. What are genymotion and nox?

Comment: Has this been replicated for another device. It could be that this device just don't work on your machine.