# Android Studio, 2 Emulator problems when running App

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm working on Android Studio 3.2.1 on Windows10. I tried some of the hints I found here for the same problems but nothing worked out for me! So I get the following error messages when trying to RUN the App on any AVD i set up so far:

Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1
& 
Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!

In my SDK Manager I see that "Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) is installed, Version 7.3.2

Anyone knows what to do to fix this problem? I would like to start seeing my Apps on AVDs

Best regards and looking forward for you answers,
Tomsho

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29136173/1531971

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29136173/emulator-error-x86-emulation-currently-requires-hardware-acceleration)

Answer (score 0):

Delete that Emulator and try to install the same again.. it works