# I can use 32bit OS virtualization but not Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, virtualization, bios

First of all, I have a problem with my BIOS, I cannot access it, so I cannot enable 64bits virtualization.

But, the thing is that I can virtualize 32bit OS (VirtualBox). However, I cannot use Android Studio virtualization (I'm using the Intel x86 emulator package), I always get the following error message "x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!".

Is there any way to solve this without accessing the BIOS?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, Open SDK Manager (In Android Studio, go to Tools > Android > SDK Manager) and Download Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer) if you haven't.

refer to: [Emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29136173/emulator-error-x86-emulation-currently-requires-hardware-acceleration)

Comment: I didn't get it to work :( PS: Sorry for late response