# I cant start emulator on Android Studio

Tags: java, android

i cant start emulator on Android Studio. And gives this error:

17:06   Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!

17:06   Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1

My cpu is AMD ryzen 5 1400.

Thanks for your support.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29136173/emulator-error-x86-emulation-currently-requires-hardware-acceleration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Emulator is not good at all , Try using Genymotion , It is always better than emulator

Otherwise check hear :

[Emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29136173/emulator-error-x86-emulation-currently-requires-hardware-acceleration)