# Error when setting up android hello world test case

Tags: android

When I set up the android hello world test case for app development I got the following error:
Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!

Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1

I have looked at the following question: [Emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29136173/emulator-error-x86-emulation-currently-requires-hardware-acceleration)

However, I have installed the intelhaxm-android.exe, so that doesn't appear to be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Intelhaxm only runs on Intel CPUs, besides you should enable virtualization in BIOS/UEFI settings of your machine.

Comment: Yes enable virtualization did work. Sorry, I've just realised that was mentioned on the other question. Thanks for your help.