# Error when trying to run Android Studio Emulator for Empty Activity

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-emulator

I have tried to run an emulator but every time I do try it comes up with:

9:29 AM Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86_64 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!

9:29 AM Emulator: Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: Maybe a duplicate of this topic https://stackoverflow.com/q/29136173/1345973