# ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration

Tags: android, android-studio

In my *android-studio* when I run emulator :

```
Emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration.
```

Emulation currently requires hardware acceleration I have window 10 home try all solutions that are given on stack overflow nothing worked. anyone help me in this plz.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29136173/emulator-error-x86-emulation-currently-requires-hardware-acceleration)

Comment: I tried all this i have enabled intel virtualization technology from bios setting and when i am trying to install intelhaxm-android.exe it is saying this computer does not support intel virtualization technology it is being used by hyper v.

Answer (score 0):

There is two solutions to fix this issue.

1. Enable Hardware Accelerated from BIOS.
2. Install Hardware Accelerated in your PC.

   - Go to your sdk path. ..\sdk\extras\intel\Hardware_Accelerated_Execution_Manager\
   - You will have some files here. Just execute intelhaxm-android.exe and install it.

Then just re-start your android studio.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: i have enabled intel virtualization technology from bios setting and when i am trying to install intelhaxm-android.exe it is saying this computer does not support  intel virtualization technology it is being used by hyper v.