# Error while downloading SDK Tools in MacOs High Sierra

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, emulation, haxm

I get the following error while downloading SDK Tools in Mac machine:

"Install Android Emulator (revision: 29.3.2)" failed.
java.io.IOException: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-darwin-4333796.zip': Read timed out
, response: 200 OK
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android SDK Tools: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-darwin-4333796.zip': Read timed out
, response: 200 OK.
java.io.IOException: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-darwin-6083285.zip': Read timed out
, response: 200 OK
Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android Emulator: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/emulator-darwin-6083285.zip': Read timed out
, response: 200 OK.

Comment: maybe a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29136173/emulator-error-x86-emulation-currently-requires-hardware-acceleration

Comment: Hi Kevin, I just edited my question.

Comment: Seem like it's your network's problem. Make sure you can download the file. I can download it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that there wasn't enough space on the disk. I was working remotely and the main thing here is that android studio never shows any error details but just the error.